# How likely is it for Esperanto.SE to come out of beta?

Tags: discussion

While browsing some other language betas and proposals on Area 51, I was surprised to find [Arabic](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language) saying that the site *"didn't have enough activity during the beta and has been closed"*, as I would have expected to find this alongside other world languages. We are faring better than them in the actual numbers but besides user counts the same areas are labelled as "Needs work" at this moment as they were at the point of closure (questions / day and visits / day). Is it necessary to get everything to at least "Okay" to prevent the risk of getting closed, too? Or does it suffice to have some activity and not get stalled? It would be a terrible pity to lose this aspiring forum.

Btw. I hope I am not tiresome with my beginner questions on the main site – but when deciding whether to ask something or not I remind myself that questions per day needs to get higher anyway :-)

Comment: The success of a SE site about a language doesn't strictly depends from the number of speakers that language has.

Comment: @kiamlaluno You're right, the comparison is needless. I rewrote the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether it's likely to come out of beta, and whether it's in danger of being closed, are two different questions.

Based on what I've read about closing of beta sites, I don't think we're in danger of that right now. From what I can tell you pretty much only get closed if the site falls into disuse and can't even moderate spam. We're nowhere near that.

But as for whether it's likely to come out of beta, I had hopes at first, but as you can see, after the initial excitement of a new site, the numbers of visits and questions per day have dropped into the "needs work" status. Unless something changes to bring more traffic, I think we'll stay in beta for the foreseeable future (if there is such a thing!). But don't feel too bad; all the language-themed SE sites except Japanese and the English ones are also still in beta (though I couldn't help but hope that this one would be so awesome it would beat the odds :-P).

Comment: Good to know! I thought the 90 plus something days were the allotted time to get some momentum, and then closure would be automatic. Well, I can always spread the word :-)

Comment: It seems that SE used to be more rigid about the time frame, but changed their policy some time back, so sites can now stay in beta indefinitely. I'll try to find the link to the info on betas and graduation; I don't have it at the moment.

Comment: @LaVo Here's the updated info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites

Answer (score 1):

With hindsight we can answer this question. It was 100% likely to come out of beta!  Perhaps we got lucky with the timing of the creation of the community because we survived long enough for them to relax the rules. We graduated despite having less than a tenth of the questions per day that the Arabic community had!

[La Esperanta komunumo ne plu estas “beta”!](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232/la-esperanta-komunumo-ne-plu-estas-beta)

Comment: Hindsight doesn't tell us much about the a-priori likelihood, other than it cannot have been 0 in this case. 