# Idea to boost site usage - work alongside duolingo

Tags: discussion

According to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95499/esperanto-language), this site really needs some work. However, I recently started the duolingo course again, and every so often I have a question of *why* something is the way it is or *how* something works (more than the basic examples I get in the course.

So my idea is to create a duolingo tag that can be applied to anything that is a good answer for something in duolingo along with keeping track in the tag wiki or a meta post which answers to to which lessons.

For example, today I did Languages 1 and 2. Afterwards I wondered why a language name is always preceded by "La" even if you don't translate the "The" out of the phrase. After some searching (and ultimately starting to type a question and looking at the similar questions box) I found [this Q/A](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/494) that gave me the answer I needed.

If we could somehow mark that so the next person who has a question after finishing the Language 1 or 2 lesson, I think it might prove helpful.

Duolingo is a good place to start, but there are also several other apps and online courses that we could incorporate if this works out. Ultimately, this site will be most used by beginners who are just learning the language, the better we can adjust to that, I think the better the site will do.

In short, I want to create a duolingo tag and a list to show which answers might be most helpful for someone who just learned something and wants to go deeper.

Comment: Tags are for describing the topic of the question. Their purpose is not describing which users could find the answer interesting, nor describing the user asking the question.

Comment: And if the topic is whatever duolingo just taught them, how would you mark it? And if you still disagree, perhaps it's worth looking into making an exception here, because this site needs all the help it can get.

Comment: Stack Exchange aims to make questions helpful to any users, not just the ones using a specific site. There is a site about Drupal, but it's not only for users having an account on drupal.org (the Drupal official site); in the same way, the site about WordPress is not only for users with an account on wordpress.org. That is why a tag that is essentially saying _Hey, this question has answers useful to you, users of Duolingo!_ is going to be accepted. If you think there are questions useful for them, just find a way to share the links with them.

Comment: Also, the problem is not with users reading the questions. So, using a tag just because the question is possibly helpful to some users coming from a site is not going to help _Esperanto Language_.

Comment: Indeed, my previous comment is a missing a _not_. That is why a tag that is essentially saying _Hey, this question has answers useful to you, users of Duolingo!_ is **not** going to be accepted.

Comment: What about tagging things with "learning" or "basics"?