# La Esperanta komunumo ne plu estas “beta”!

Tags: discussion

### La Esperanta komunumo ne plu estas “beta”!

Ni esperas, ke vi havis feliĉan [Zamenhofan Tagon](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamenhofa_Tago)!

Post 5 jaroj da kontribuoj kaj laborado pri la Esperanta komunumo ĉe Stack Exchange, ekde la 16a de decembro 2021 ĝi ne plu estas “beta”. Ĝi nun konkretiĝis kiel stabila kaj fidebla retejo, kiel [multaj aliaj komunumoj](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-58-sites-that-just-left-beta) de Stack Exchange.

Dankon al ĉiuj pro via daŭra laboro kaj volontemo por ebligi ĉi tion!

---

### The Esperanto community has left the beta phase!

We hope that you had a great [Zamenhof Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamenhof_Day)!

After 5 years of contributions and hard work on the Esperanto community of Stack Exchange, from the 16th of December 2021 it is no longer “beta”. It has graduated to be a fully stable and reliable website like [many of the other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-58-sites-that-just-left-beta) Stack Exchange communities.

Thanks a lot to everyone for your continued work and community spirit that has made this possible!

Comment:  Gratulon al ni ĉiuj! 